# Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types "A" | "B", but '===' can?

Tags: typescript, if-statement, typescript-2.5

I have read [Operator '==' cannot be applied to types x and y in Typescript 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243143/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-x-and-y-in-typescript-2) and it has not been informative to my case.

In TypeScript 2.5.3, we define many models using string enums of the form:

```
export interface Event {
   category: "MORNING" | "NIGHT";
   enabled: boolean;
}
```

And then apply comparators to them like:

```
morning = events.filter(event => event.category === 'MORNING');
```

without complaint.

Now, in this code fragment:

```
if (event.enabled || event.category === 'MORNING') {
 // something
}
else if (event.category !== 'MORNING') {
 // something else
}
```

I get the `Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types '"MORNING"' and '"NIGHT"'` compile error in the `else if` condition, *but not* in the `if` condition, which uses the same (but opposite) comparator.

Reducing the example further, the following compiles:

```
if (event.category !== 'MORNING') {
 // something
}
else if (event.category !== 'MORNING') {
 // something else
}
```

And this compiles:

```
if (event.category !== 'MORNING') {
 // something
}
else if (event.category === 'MORNING') {
 // something else
}
```

Whereas *this throws an error* (in the `else if` line):

```
if (event.category === 'MORNING') {
 // something
}
else if (event.category !== 'MORNING') {
 // something else
}
```

**What fundamental property of the type-checker have I misunderstood?**

(Note: The final examples are reduced from more complex situations, so I cannot use a simple `else`.)

Comment: Your `else if` condition makes no sense.
The `if` condition is `event.enabled || event.category === 'MORNING'`, so by definition, if that condition was not true, then by definition, `event.category` is `'NIGHT'` and `event.category !== 'MORNING'` is true. Why is there a need to check it again? If that's not an accurate representation of the condition you actually need to check, please give us an example that _is_ an accurate representation of it.

Comment: @JLRishe Is right; I've tried every combination where your conditional isn't redundant and it works. Something to do with type narrowing.

Comment: This _is_ happening for more or less the same reason as the matter in the question you linked to.

Comment: @JLRishe Indeed, but as I explained, this is a _reduced (and fairly contrived) example_ from a more complex decision matrix with other things in it that I progressively removed to arrive at the final cases. In the real code, `category` is also more complex, but in building my [mcve], I noted identical behaviour with the provided example. Adding the real wall of code would not have added value to the question as I only wanted to know why those three final cases existed. The answer, which I am grateful for you having provided, is _control flow based type analysis._ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting an error because the compiler already knows that at the point of the `else if` condition, `event.category` is not `'MORNING'` and will no longer allow you to compare `event.category` to it.

If this condition evaluates to `false`,

```
if (event.enabled || event.category === 'MORNING') {
 // something
}
```

then by definition, `event.category` is *not* `'MORNING'` and is therefore `'NIGHT'`. The compiler won't allow you to compare it to `'MORNING'` again (and indeed there's no point in comparing it to `'MORNING'` again), because it's already known to not be `'MORNING'` at the point that the `else if` condition is being evaluated.

Incidentally, the following produces a compile error for essentially the same reason:

```
if (event.category !== 'MORNING') {
 // something
}
else if (event.category !== 'NIGHT') {
 // something else
}
```

As does this:

```
if (event.category === 'MORNING' || event.category !== 'MORNING') {
 // something
}
```

This is due to the way that TypeScript "narrows down" union types as it evaluates subsequent boolean expressions.

As suggested in the comments below, please see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis, and also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.24

Comment: I was in the middle of writing a more verbose version of this, but I'll give up now!  You might want to mention that this is due to TypeScript's [control flow based type analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis), which is how it goes about narrowing `event.category`.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is right and has to do with type checking system in Typescript and TypeGuards. Consider:

Your fist example:

```
if (event.category !== 'MORNING') {
 // something
}
else if (event.category === 'MORNING') {
 // something else
}
```

After first `if` typescript cannot assume anything about type of `category`. Simple check if something is not equal to some kind of value does tell us nothing about type of variable. In next chains of `else if` it could be anything that matches your variable type.

Not working example:

```
if (event.category === 'MORNING') {
 // something
}
else if (event.category !== 'MORNING') {
 // something else
}
```

But if you check the other way around, you know for sure that `category` cannot be equal to `'MORNING'`, so Typescript changes your type. Its some kind of type narrowing.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#424-type-guards More info in spec C:

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!