# operator === will always return 'false' since the types have no overlap

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have this code

```
enum Example {
  First = "First",
  Second = "Second"
}

let a = [1, 2];

let newStatus: Example = Example.First;

a.forEach(i => {
  newStatus = Example.Second;
});

if (newStatus === Example.Second) {
  // do something
}
```

Expected: No errors

Actual: Error: [ts] This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Example.First' and 'Example.Second' have no overlap. [2367]

Comment: Not 100% duplicate, but the explanation is the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626568/why-boolean-becomes-true/48627130#48627130. Basically control flow analysis limitation, use   `let newStatus = Example.First as Example;` instead

Comment: post as answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the comment by @titian-cernicova-dragomir and the answer on [Why boolean becomes true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626568/why-boolean-becomes-true/48627130#48627130) you can put a casting operator in to force the compiler to treat the enum as the enum, not just the last value of the enum it thought it was assigned.

So, in your case, you can change line 8 to

```
let newStatus: Example = Example.First as Example;
```

Or, if that doesn't fix it, you can change the comparison itself

```
if (newStatus === (Example.Second as Example)) {
  // do something
}
```

I prefer to change the comparison as it is the line that the compiler is barfing over, but it entirely depends on how many comparisons you have vs how many assignments you have and which feels more understandable to you.

Comment: wow similar issue and this worked! thank you sir. I could not and event GPT could not figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I know, I am bit late but alternate solution to your problem is the ES6 `includes` method to check the condition with string, type or enums in typescript. For better understanding see the code.

```
enum Example {
  First = "First",
  Second = "Second"
}

let a = [1, 2];

let newStatus: Example = Example.First;

a.forEach(i => {
  newStatus = Example.First;
});

if (newStatus.includes(Example.Second)) {
  
}
```