# How to implement "Either" functionality of Functional language in typescript

Tags: typescript

In Functional languages, I can define a method where the signature clearly says that either the method returns Type A or Type B. ex:

```
class AppError(message: String)
public convertToString(input: Int) : Either[AppError, String]
```

The left side is always the un-happy path, and right side is the happy path. I am trying to do something similar in typescript. I wrote this code

```
type AppError = {message: String, errorCode: number}
function doSomething(param1: number) : AppError | string {
  if (param1 < 0) {
    return {"message": "param1 cannot be less than 0"}
  } else {
    return +param1
  }
}
const result3 = doSomething(-1)
if (typeof result3 === "AppError") {
  console.log("got this exception" + result3.message)
} else 
  console.log("got result " + result3)
}
```

But the typescript compiler says

```
This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | 
"boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and '"AppError"' have no 
overlap.ts(2367)
```

I googled and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626568/why-boolean-becomes-true/48627130#48627130) thread but I still don't understand why will typeof x always be false? My code is returning the AppError object if you pass a negative number and in that case, the `typeof result3 === 'AppError'` should evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` in JavaScript and TypeScript does not return a class name or constructor name, but it only returns the *native* JavaScript value-type-name, which is **only** one of:

```
'string'
'number'
'bigint'
'boolean'
'symbol'
'undefined'
'object'        // Note that `typeof aNullVar` evalutes to `'object'` btw.
'function'
```

What you want is [a TypeScript **type guard** function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), which is used for runtime type checking that the compiler will "trust" to enforce type-safety.

Note how the return-type of `isAppError` below is `value is AppError`.

Like so:

```
function isAppError( value: string | AppError ): value is AppError {
    return typeof value === 'object'
        && ( value !== null )
        && ( 'message' in value )
        && ( 'errorCode' in value )
        && ( typeof (value as AppError).errorCode === 'number' );
}
```

This `isAppError` function can probably be simplified (e.g. you don't need the `value !=== null` check if you're in strict-mode.

And used like so:

```
if( isAppError( result3 ) ) {
    // TypeScript *knows* that `result3` is of-type `AppError` inside this `if` statement's scope.

    console.log( result3.errorCode ); // TypeScript knows that result3 is AppError here.
}
else {
    // If `result3`'s type is an intersection type of only 2 types then TypeScript *knows& that result3 is of-type `string` inside this `else` statement's scope.

    console.log( result3.substring(1) );  // TypeScript knows that result3 is string here.
}
```