# Operator '==' cannot be applied to types string and number

Tags: typescript, operator-keyword

How to check the value of a number?

```
for(var index in this.choicesDM) {
  if(index == 0) {
    this.currentChoice = this.choicesDM[index]
  }
}
```

Here I get the **error as mentioned** in the **title** of the question. I also tried to explicitly define the type of index. But didn't work.
Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39243442/2904573) but didn't got the solution.

Comment: Can you post the code which shows how you explicitly define the type of index?

Comment: Are you sure it is `index` and not a difference between `currentChoice and `choicesDM[index]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript (and thus, TypeScript), the `in` operator returns a string. This is because `for in` loops iterate over an *object*'s keys, which are strings in JavaScript/TypeScript. So, when you compare `index == 0`, `index` is a string and `0` is an integer, thus the error.

Note what I said before, though, that `for in` enumerates over an object's properties. In the case of arrays, this also includes things like the `length` property, so it's generally a bad idea to loop over arrays with `for in`. What you might want instead is a `for of` loop, where `of` gives you the value of each object in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because == and other related comparison operators operate on operands with same type or type of 1 operand should be subtype of other operand. But in your case 0 is integer and **"index"** is string. Hence the error.