# Typescript == not working directly with values. Like 'if(1==2)' is not allowed

Tags: angular, typescript, operators

I am creating Angular application with code coverage report.

In one method I want to skip some line using some false condition, So I tried to write one function in my component like:

```
sum(num1:number,num2:number){
    if(1 == 2)
    {
        //Some Code
    }
     return num1+num2;
}
```

But it is giving me error message like

Operator '==' cannot be applied to type '1' and '2'

In some cases it is allowing and in some cases it is not allowing like:

```
if(1 != 2) //not allowed
if(1 == 2) //not allowed
if('1' == '2') //not allowed
if(1===2) //not allowed

if(2 == 2) //allowed
if(2 != 2) //allowed
if('1' == '1') //allowed
if(1===1) //allowed
if(parseInt('1') == parseInt('2')) //allowed
```

Can anyone explain about these scenarios?

Comment: This is because you should use === instead of == for type checking

Comment: I tried 1===2 also but not working. Editing my question with these scenarios.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator '==' cannot be applied to types x and y in Typescript 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243143/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-x-and-y-in-typescript-2)

Comment: I think you mean TypeScript *is* working by giving you an error. :) Duplicate question should explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using comparison operators on values of different types is usually an error, so TypeScript warns about that:

```
if (1 === "1") {} // error
```

TypeScript treats numeric and string literals as [their own types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), so comparing two different literals will be an error for the same reason:

```
if (1 === 2) {} // error
```

Note that comparing two literals in JavaScript is usually guaranteed to have a known outcome.  There's only one possible result for `(1 == 2)`.  So generally there's not much use to writing that code since you can replace it with its known outcome: `(1 == 2)` can be replaced with `false`, and `(1 === 1)` can be replaced with `true`.  And so, there's not much of a reason for the language maintainers to care about adding support for comparing two different literals... it's hard to imagine a valid use case for comparing literals that isn't better served by *not* comparing literals.

However, if you really need to make such a comparison you can widen (one of) the literal types to their common supertype, like `number` or `string`:

```
if (1 as number == 2) { console.log("nope"); } // works
if ('1' as string == '2') { console.log("nope"); } // works
```

You are telling TypeScript to consider `1` not as the literal `1` but as a `number`, and that *can* be compared to `2`.  But again, you don't really need to do that.  Instead, you can do:

```
if (false) { console.log("nope"); } // unreachable code detected!
```

That new warning is also a good one.  Usually, unreachable code is a sign of an error.  Personally I'd rather just comment that code out or remove it than leave unreachable code.  Or just leave the error as a reminder that you should go back and clean it up.

However, if you really want an `if (false) {}` scenario to work without an error, the more idiomatic way to do it would be something like

```
if (false as boolean) { console.log("nope"); } // works
```

where you're telling the compiler to consider `false` to be just a `boolean`, and therefore it no longer realizes or cares that the code after the conditional is unreachable.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please,chekout once whether it is number or string,because in some scenario if you are geting values from other component it may/may not in number format it is in string quoted number like '12345' insted of 12345,so it may create some problem