# how typescript enum value compares?

Tags: typescript, enums

[image]

```
enum A {
   a = 1,
   b = 2
}

namespace N1 {
   export enum A {
       a = 1,
       b = 2
   }
}
// it will pass type check
console.log(A.a === N1.A.a)
```

when I remove const keyword, the expression will pass type check.

But if const was added, tsc says

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'A' and
> 'N1.A' have no overlap.

I want to know how enums in TS compare enum value under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`link`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums)

> Const enums can only use constant enum expressions and unlike regular
> enums they are completely removed during compilation. Const enum
> members are inlined at use sites. This is possible since const enums
> cannot have computed members.

***To illustrate consider below code -***

```
enum A {
   a = 1,
   b = 2
}

namespace N1 {
   export const enum A {
       a = 1,
       b = 2
   }
}

console.log(N1.A.a);
console.log(A.a);
```

***which will be transpiled to -***

```
"use strict";
var A;
(function (A) {
    A[A["a"] = 1] = "a";
    A[A["b"] = 2] = "b";
})(A || (A = {}));
console.log(1);
console.log(A.a);
```

***As you can see -***

1. There is no reference of `const enum A` in the transpiled code.
2. The console output of printing `N1.A.a` converted to `literal type` `1`.

So at compile time the `literal type 1` and `A.a` cannot be compared and you have to typecast the `const enum` to number like below -

```
console.log(N1.A.a as number === A.a)
```

You can further check the literal type comparison in below thread -

[Operator '==' cannot be applied to types x and y in Typescript 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243143/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-x-and-y-in-typescript-2)

Comment: if you add const keyword before first enum definition(the one without namespace), tsc will still show the same error. why literal type 1 can not be equal to literal type 1?

Comment: I hope you went through the SO thread that I posted in my answer! For literal type comparisons typecast is required.