# error TS2365: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'. in Anglar

Tags: angular, typescript

**i am trying to compile this code but it get error....**

**.html**
...

```
<div *ngIf="(dateObj | date:'h') >= 5; else elseBlock2">
    <h2>this is if</h2>
</div>

<ng-template #elseBlock2>
    <h2>else block</h2>
</ng-template>
```

...

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'weather-app';
  dateObj:number = Date.now();
}
```

**error**

```
error TS2365: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.

6 <div *ngIf="(dateObj | date:'h') >= 5; else elseBlock2">
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

when i did this type of process before another project then it works properly but in this project get this error.please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operator '==' cannot be applied to types x and y in Typescript 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243143/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-x-and-y-in-typescript-2)

Answer (score 0):

Actually issue is date.Now not return number it always return date format so if you want to compare hour with 5 just simple put 5 in string format

like

```
if(dateobj>'5'){
console.log("done")
}
```

Comment: but , in your code here if statement will not be work, because i also tried this method, but in my case we had change our workspace then it worked properly. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

**finally i got solution of this problem:**

Actually issue was in my **workspace**, when i changed our workspace then this code worked properly.there was no any error in this code.